# При клике на атрибут товара (цвет) не меняется основное изображение woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте! 
Такая проблема: при клике на атрибут товара (цвет) не меняется основное изображение, хотя все делаю правильно. В корзине, при добавлении нужная картинка отображается. Тема - Nitro, последнее обновление woocommerce. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, упоминание платной темы вряд ли чем поможет - не думаю, что велика вероятность обнаружить ее у посетителей SO ru. А что в консоли браузера? Скорее всего, какие-то сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: И почему вы решили, что картинка товара должна меняться? Вот демо  - http://nitro.woorockets.com/niche-08/product/gel-lyte-v-purple-2/ и где тут смена картинки при нажатии на цвет? Полагаю, что ваши ожидания от темы не соответствуют функционалу.

Comment: я как раз и ищу как возможно это включить

Comment: Нет такой функции в теме.

Comment: это понятно, я говорю о том, что это вполне возможно реализовать ( если это уже прописано в плагине woocommerce). В надежде на то, что найдется человек, который решал эту проблему в этой теме

Comment: В плагине woocommerce прописана возможность задавать атрибуты товара: размер, запах, или цвет - например. Нигде в WooCommerce нет привязки атрибута к картинке товара. Это могло бы быть реализовано в теме, но и в теме этого нет. Надо писать свой код, под данную тему. И я сильно сомневаюсь, что тут найдётся человек, который уже такую тему купил, да ещё именно такое дополнение разработал. Лучше обратиться к фрилансерам.